# Base64 Inline Image use more than once

Tags: html, image, base64, inline

is it possible to use the Data of an Base64 encoded inline-image more than once? Or do I have to write the Data in every img statement?

Thanks in common

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS to specify the content for the image

```css
.myImage {
  content: url('data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQALMPAAAAAIAAAACAAICAAAAAgIAAgACAgMDAwICAgP8AAAD/AP//AAAA//8A/wD//////yH5BAEAAA8ALAAAAAAQABAAQAQ78EkJqp10LaB759sDVh4ZiqVVTqC3om6smVvcAmz74Zioz7zMRmfC/WTAGXI0Ws5gtc+HhXz2fJagJAIAOw==');
}
```

```html
<img src="#" class="myImage" />
```

But if you're looking to do something in pure HTML there isn't any way to reuse data URIs.